# Appending a transformed column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, append, transform, pyspark

I am running a logistic regression on data frame, and as logistic regression function in spark does not take in categorical vriable I am  transforming it.

I am using string indexer transformer.

```
indexer=StringIndexer(inputCol="classname",outputCol="ClassCategory")
```

I want to append this transform column back to dataframe.
df.withColumn does not let me do that because object indexer is not a column.

Is there a way to transform and append.

Comment: Maybe the examples in this link can help you: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer

Comment: Hi I have gone through the link and found stringIndexer as the most efficient way to make indices of my string value, to feed into the model. However I am still look to join the indexed table into my dataframe.

Comment: have you tried `indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the examples of the [Spark ML Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer), you can try the following:

```
// Original data is in "df"
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="classname",outputCol="ClassCategory")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

The `indexed` object will be a dataframe with a new column called "ClassCategory" (the name passed as `outputCol`).